# I am unable to install plotly and geopandas package with pip, what should I do?

Tags: python, cmd, pip, installation, plotly

I've tried to install plotly using pip in the windows CMD as administrator but I keep getting the following error:

```
$pip install plotly
Collecting plotly
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x05EA24F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/plotly/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x05E663F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/plotly/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x05E79450>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/plotly/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x05E79870>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/plotly/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x05E79BD0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/plotly/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement plotly (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for plotly
```

I have python 3.7, and windows 10. I also have the latest version of pip and anaconda as of 06/14-19 if it matters.

Comment: I tried the same command `pip install plotly` in an new virtual environment and there is no problem. (Windows 10, Python 3.7 Anaconda)

Answer (score 1):

Please, give some more specific info. System, python version, etc. Only tried on conda?
try mb:

```
sudo pip install plotly
```

or

```
sudo pip3 install plotly
```

On conda there is chance that this works:

```
conda install -c plotly plotly
```

Comment: I changed my question please help!

Comment: I still don't get information what about commands that i mentioned above... did You checked them? If yes, what happened? (the command with conda ofc)

Comment: if still nothing- try disable antivirus, or anything that can block connection for pip.

Comment: This appears to be on Windows. Using `sudo` does not apply. This answer could/should be deleted.

Comment: My answer was posted before editing the question, and there was no information about system and environment. read carefully. Your comment should be deleted, Mr Moderator